# TSQL Stored Procedure with parameters & variables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am a beginner with TSQL scripting and I need a hand to get my stored procedure to work as intended.

I want to use the @date parameter in my sp to take logg@date - in ccyymmdd format. Also, is there any security flaws or optimisation i could think of more than the Tablock? Could tablock become a problem in the future?

To clearify problem:
When I do the Bulk Insert, I want the data to get into the db depending on @datum and currently it is not working as intended. Any hints would be appreciated. batch file will be running on daily schedule to insert data into dbname@datum.

Current SP code:

```
USE [dbname]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[fillDbTablelogg]    Script Date: 2016-02-26 16:47:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

 =============================================
 Author:        <Author,,Name>
 Create date:   <Create Date,,>
 Description:   <Description,,>
 =============================================
ALTER PROC [dbo].[fillDbname]
@datum date(8)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Declare @bulkInsert NVARCHAR(MAX)



Declare @pathRail nvarchar(100)  = 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\';
Declare @pathDate nvarchar(100) = convert(char, getdate(), 12); 
--Want to use my @Date parameter instead, sending in 8 digits so ccyymmdd
Declare @fromPath NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@pathRail' + '20' + '@pathDate' + '.tab';
--should print 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\pathRailccyymmdd.tab'


Declare @ErrorPath nvarchar(100) = 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\err';
--x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\err2014-11-22.12:45:34.log
Declare @ErrorNow nvarchar(100) = curdate() + '.' + curtime() + '.log';
Declare @errorFilePath NVARCHAR (100) = @ErrorPath + @ErrorNow;

--Will change this formatfilename later to something more suiting, I have a working XML format file created with bcp.
Declare @formatFile nvarchar (100) = 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\dbo.nameccyymmdd.xml';

set @bulkInsert =  '
BULK INSERT dbname.logg' + @datum + 'FROM' + @fromPath +'
WITH 
    (
   FIRSTROW = 1,
   ORDER (Id),
   CODEPAGE = Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS,
   FIELDTERMINATOR = \t,
   ROWTERMINATOR = 0x0a,
   TABLOCK,
   ERRORFILE = @errorFilePath,
   FORMATFILE = @formatFile, 
   --KEEPNULLS
   );'
   exec(@bulkInsert)
   end
```

Fixed: Added datatypes to all variables. Made sure all variables that was used were created first. edited @datum variable to datatype date instead of varchar.

Comment: First of all you should use the correct datatypes...always. If you are dealing with date information you should use date, not varchar. Then you have tons of syntax errors, variables defined with no datatypes, variable being used that aren't defined.

Comment: What variable is not defined in script? Thanks for input @SeanLange

Comment: @datum is not defined anywhere in there. Also, what is curdate() and curtime(). Those look like mysql functions. And you really should make you input parameter be a date instead of varchar(8). What happens when you pass in 'a8djf'?

Comment: '@datum' is supposed to replace '@pathDate' - It will be implemented with a batch file (.bat) on a daily schedule.

Comment: So what is wrong with your script at this point?   Are you getting an error?

Comment: When I do the Bulk Insert, I want the data to get into the db depending on @datum and currently it is not working as intended. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DECLARE` statements need to include datatype:

```
Declare @pathRail varchar(31) = 'x:\xxxx\SYSTEMID\';
Declare @pathDate varchar(15) = convert(char, getdate(), 12);
```

Comment: Fixed syntax errors & edited some logic. I got a working formating file now! Accepted as answer